# Issue with ng-selected in Angular Select

Tags: html, angularjs, select, ng-options

I currently have two separate arrays that I am trying to use to create a Select in Angular.js

My layout is like this:
One array has all of my information for the table as well as a foreign key ID that links to the second table.

The second array has a key and a string value name.

What I am wanting to do is use the select in my html table so the user can select the ID that will be used in the first array by viewing the names listed in the second array.

Here is what my current code looks like (with i coming from the ng-repeat and ItemType being the second array)

```
           <select ng-model="i.ItemTypeID"
                   ng-options="t.Name as t.Name for t in ItemType"
                   ng-selected="{{i.ItemTypeID == t.ItemTypeID}}">
           </select>
```

**EDIT:**
To further clarify, I am using a pagination in place of ng-repeat for my project, but to my knowledge they act similarly. Here is the code for that:

```
<tr dir-paginate-start="i in Item|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:scannedValue|itemsPerPage:5" id="display">
```

Comment: Can you please show roughly what you want . i am really confused with first and second table relation and where would be Select list ?

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing, I will try to explain it a little better. Basically I have a html table that will have a Type column. This column should have a Select list for the user to select from a list of Types. The data that I am populating the html Table only has the ItemTypeID value, but I would like the user to be able to select this ID by using the names from the TypeList (table2) I have filled previously. The main relation between the two tables is that table 1 has a foreign key relation to the second tables primary key (ItemTypeID).

Comment: Can you show the ng-repeat code? And also, when you say 'table' are you meaning a JavaScript list/array?

Comment: Sure, I will edit it to my original question so it can be more noticeable. Also, I do mean a Javascript array, I am used to calling them tables because of SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my issue. I was trying to use the Name in the ng-options instead of the ID. By changing the code to the following I was able to make it work for me:

```
       <select ng-model="i.ItemTypeID"
               ng-options="t.ItemTypeID as t.Name for t in ItemType"
       </select>
```

Comment: you also removed the ng-selected attribute. It not belongs to <select> tag